Is SHA authentication available for BGP?
Perhaps the question should be "Is SHA authentication available for the Cisco implementation of BGP" but just in case the limitation is somehow at the protocol level, I kept it general.  The point is, I can't find any cisco documentation for BGP authentication using SHA

Which Cisco OS? IOS-XR supports HMAC-MD5 and HMAC-SHA1-12.

A quick google for BGP authentication indicates that it does support a variety of options for authentication of BGP peer sessions. Implementations vary depending on the platform in question.

Appreciate the quick Google to match my longer Google but need configuration examples or, even better, actual documentation

Not that I'm aware of. BGP's authentication method is MD5. I've not heard of an RFC to modernize this. Cisco supports encrypting the entire TCP connection (beyond BGP) using key-chains. (plenty of docs on this)

it's pretty clear why chatgpt is the new stackexchange...
